# VB.NET ComboBox Not Recognising Text Change

Tags: vb.net

I have an application whereby I have the behaviour of 2 groupboxes enable/disable based on the value in a combobox.

This combobox however the behaviour for the group boxes only works when I leave the field by tab or click, not when the text changes.

I have tried using the Leave, TextChanged, Validated Events and everytime I have to actually "Leave" the field for it to perform the enabled/disabled of the groupboxes and their subsequent controls.

I need it so that when they choose 1 of the 3 options it immediately changes and doesn't work when they leave the field but when they choose the correct word.

Any assistance would be great I'm tearing my hair out here.

Comment: It seems to work as expected. Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: The Text of a ComboBox is changed when an item is selected. So, if you want the event to trigger only on user intervention, subscribe to `SelectionChangeCommitted`. otherwise to `SelectedIndexChanged`. The Text itself is better left alone. It's used to trigger the AutoComplete feature. Or a custom, *manual*, one.  I assume, from the names, that you're referring to WinForms controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the event on your combo boxes

```
SelectedIndexChanged
```

To stop the user from leaving an invalid field use the event

```
Validating
```

set the e.cancel to True if the validation fails